# how to fetch missed jobs from scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I am using BackgroundScheduler scheduler to schedule my jobs.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore

jobstores = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(engine=my_db_engine)}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

job = scheduler.add_job(my_job, run_date=some_future_time, misfire_grace_time=60)
```

I want to fetch missed jobs for scheduler which passed misfire_grace_time. The `scheduler.get_jobs()` will give only future jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're really after, but you can add a listener for missed jobs:

```
def listener(event):
    ...

scheduler.add_listener(listener, EVENT_JOB_MISSED)
```

Some documentation [here](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/events.html#module-apscheduler.events).

Comment: and inside the job we can get the job with `event.jobstore.lookup_job(event.job_id)`. Or is there a better way?

Comment: The executor does not pass the job it to the job function, so unless you use a predetermined job id which you pass to the target function as an argument, there is no way the target function would know the job id.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I will use pretermined ids to access the job from the listener